# Display PDF from chatter files in Visualforce Page

Tags: javascript, api, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I am storing pdfs as chatter files in our SF org which is working well except for the fact that displaying these PDF's to the users is very challenging, especially on mobile device (eg ipad)
I have tracked down some good javascript PDF viewers which will behave fairly on well on ipad.
The challenge is delivering the pdf file from to these viewers.

Most of them require a local pdf file to view but there are some like google view which will take a url to the pdf for eg
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://urltopdf

The pdf is available via a chatter GET as follows:
https://cs2.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/chatter/files/{docId}/content?versionNumber=1
The problem ofcourse is that I need to pass in an authentication header. If I just pass that url to google viewer it fails because of Authentication as its not passing in the Auth header.

I tried a few things..

- Built a proxy API in Salesforce which Google viewer calls, that API calls chatter and then returns the file to google docs view
  **PROBLEM: Custom SF APIs have a 6mb limit which means that if the pdf is bigger than 6mb it wont work!**
- Built a proxy API external to SF (to get around the 6mb limit) including some interesting ways to persist the authentication
  **PROBLEM: There are too many hops and the google viewer is not getting back the data in time...its calling the external proxy API which is then calling the chatter API which then has to return the pdf data back to the external proxy API and then back to Salesforce (ridiculous I know).**

So I am stuck.....
I thought that as of Spring 13' Chatter API is accessible without any special authentication from Javascript on a VF page.
Is that true?
Will this url work without any auth header when called from javascript on a VF page? https://cs2.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/chatter/files/{docId}/content?versionNumber=1
It doesnt seem to work for me and definitely wont work when going via google viewer.

Would really appreciate any suggestions how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please dont hate me, I am trying to get some rep.

You can query the static resources for the docid and load the file by ajax request on the VF page.

After that its a matter of using data:image/png;base64 added to the base64 to add it to a canvas.  You can also add a download tag to the canvas so it will download or open it in another window will give the user the browser pdf explorer.

If you use canvas be careful with Safari when you resize.  If you get a really long number it will crap out on the canvas.  I spent hours on that one.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I have some sample code that does that, I will dig it up if you want to try it.

Comment: Been through that...i dont remember the exact issue but it was at least one or all of the following
- You quickly hit salesforce limits when the pdf is medium to large size, - doesnt work in all browsers, - had issues on mobile devices